# How to check if username and password are correct in web2py?

Tags: javascript, web2py

I want to check if the username and password which is in a database are correct.
For this i made a javascript function.

```
    function checkLogin() {
          username = (document.getElementById('login').value
          password = document.getElementById('password').value)

          if (username == db.Membership.select(username)){

               alert("it exists")
```

So this function gets called everytime when someone clicks on Log in after they have entered their details. Is it possible to check if username and password are correct?

Answer (score 1):

In web2py, `db.Membership.select(username)` is Python code and must be run on the server in a model or controller (or module) -- it is not Javascript and cannot be run in the browser.

Furthermore, it doesn't make sense to simply check in the browser whether a user's login credentials are valid because (a) you need to know on the server whether a user is logged in (in order to control access to functions and resources on the server) and (b) an attacker could simply run some Javascript in the browser console to fake a valid login.

In web2py, a user's logged in status is stored in the session, which is either stored on the server (in a file or in the database) or in an encrypted and signed cookie (which cannot be altered from the client side). The authentication itself must happen on the server (so it cannot be faked).

If you want to log a user in, you should use the standard login mechanism. If you want the login submission to be handled via Ajax, you can post the credentials to a web2py controller function, and in the controller, you can call `auth.login_bare(username, password)`, which will either log in the user (i.e., update the session to indicate login) or return `False` if the login fails.